# Preparing a statement causes SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK when db-journal file exists

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm having an issue using the sqlite3 API in C (Linux RHEL5, 64 bit) to recover from a crash where I'm left with a `.db` and a `.db-journal` file.

If I examine the `.db` file with the `sqlite3` binary itself and run `SELECT * from t;`, the binary removes the `.db-journal` file and recovers fine.

In my app however, I prepare the same statement on a valid `sqlite*` and it returns `SQLITE_IOERR | SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK`:

```
#define SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK              (SQLITE_IOERR | (15<<8))
#define SQLITE_IOERR       10   /* Some kind of disk I/O error occurred */
```

How can I tell sqlite that I want it to recover with the db-journal file?

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3* db_ptr = NULL;
    int sqlite_result = SQLITE_ERROR;
    sqlite3_stmt* query=NULL;
    int prepare_result=-1;

    if ( argc > 2 )
    {
        sqlite_result = sqlite3_open_v2(argv[1],
                                        &db_ptr,
                                        SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,
                                        NULL);
        if ( sqlite_result == SQLITE_OK )
        {
            sqlite3_extended_result_codes(db_ptr,1);
            prepare_result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_ptr,
                                                argv[2],
                                                strlen(argv[2])+1,
                                                &query,
                                                NULL);
            sqlite3_close(db_ptr);
            if ( prepare_result != SQLITE_OK )
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: %d\n",prepare_result);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stdout,"Success\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return prepare_result;
}
```

Result:

```
Error: 3850
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer while reading over my question...obviously to recover to the db file, the program needs to open it with READWRITE access.  Duh.  Changing:

```
    sqlite_result = sqlite3_open_v2(argv[1],
                                    &db_ptr,
                                    SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,
                                    NULL);
```

to:

```
    sqlite_result = sqlite3_open_v2(argv[1],
                                    &db_ptr,
                                    SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,
                                    NULL);
```

fixes the issue.  In the real program, not the test app, I had the open so far away from the prepare statement that I didn't even notice it was READONLY in that particular case.